# How do I get terminal to update variables in a script?

Tags: python, terminal, global-variables, command-line-arguments

I have a folder of python scripts that looks like this...

```
 global_variables.py
 main.py
 helper_1.py 
 ...
 helper_n.py
```

- main.py is the script that I run.
- The helper.py scripts are imported by main.py.
- **global_variables.py provides global variables that ALL of the python scripts use**.

I want to pass arguments into main.py like this:

```
user$ python main.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

where the args are 3-4 variables in global_variables.py (not all of them; there are ~50 variables defined in there). If I didn't have the helper.py scripts, I would implement this by writing in main.py

```
import sys
import global_variables

global_variables.var1 = arg1
global_variables.var2 = arg2
...
```

Unfortunately, these changes don't propagate to the other helper.py scripts.

What is the most elegant solution to fix this issue? What I could do is not use global variables and pass all the arguments manually to each python script, *but this will look hideous and, given the length of all the scripts put together (~4000 lines of code), will take me hours and hours (including debugging time).*

Essentially, what I want:

```
user$ python main.py arg1 arg2 ...
```

to do is first update the variables in `global_variables.py`, and **then** run `main.py`. Perhaps this is possible?

Comment: Updating the variables *in memory* doesn't change the source code. That would be wacky.

Comment: so you're saying that my last suggestion is not possible?

Comment: Please show us one of those problematic `helper_*.py` files. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this correctly reflects your project setup, but this simple approach works as expected:

#### main.py

```
import sys
import global_vars

global_vars.x = sys.argv[1]
print "main: %s" % global_vars.x

import helper
helper.f()
```

#### helper.py

```
import global_vars

print "helper: %s" % global_vars.x

def f():
    print "helper: f: %s" % global_vars.x
```

#### global_vars.py

```
x = "<initial value>"
```

When called as:

```
$ python main.py X
```

outputs:

```
main: X
helper: X
helper: f: X
```

The somewhat "delayed" `import helper` ensures *all* `helper.py` module code sees the updated `global_vars` values as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're trying to do but could you use the `shelve` module to create a shelve where you stored all the global data as keys?

Something like this?

```
# main script
import shelve
myglobals = shelve.open("myglobals")
myglobals['varname1'] = value1
myglobals['varname2'] = value2
myglobals.close()
```

then in the other scripts to access the 'globals':

```
# helper script
import shelve
myglobals = shelve.open("myglobals")
value1 = myglobals['varname1']
value2 = myglobals['varname2']
myglobals.close()
```